# Triggers not working as expected for SET columns in mariadb

Tags: mariadb

This dosen't work, I create the trigger just fine but when I insert something in that table a get #1054 - Unknown column 'available_methods' in 'field list'

```
CREATE TRIGGER `add_notification_type` AFTER INSERT ON `notification_types`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO unit_templates (unit, idkey, method)
    SELECT u.id AS unit, NEW.idkey, m.method
    FROM units AS u
    JOIN (
            SELECT 'sms' as method
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'push'
            UNION ALL
           SELECT 'email'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'chat'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'info'
    ) AS m ON FIND_IN_SET(m.method, NEW.available_methods) > 0;
END
```

This works:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `add_notification_type` AFTER INSERT ON `notification_types`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE available_methods_var VARCHAR(255);

    SET available_methods_var = NEW.available_methods;

    INSERT IGNORE INTO unit_templates (unit, idkey, method)
    SELECT u.id AS unit, NEW.idkey, m.method
    FROM units AS u
    JOIN (
        SELECT 'sms' as method
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'push'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'email'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'chat'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'info'
    ) AS m ON FIND_IN_SET(m.method, available_methods_var) > 0;
END
```

The problem appears only for columns of type SET/ENUM (actually I've tried only SET). The strange thing is that on mariadb 10.3 the problem appeared only on AFTER UPDATE triggers but on AFTER INSERT it was working. After upgrading to mariadb 11 the AFTER insert wasn't working any more and I had to declare the variables before and not use the NEW.available_methods in query.

Does anyone knows why this happens? I even tried to ask chatgpt but his answer was and i quote "it's strange" :)). He tolled me that it was probably something to do with the version of mariadb but that doesn't explain things.

Thanks in advance

I tried the first variant first and I was expecting it to work

--UPDATE--

These are the tables involved:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `notification_types`
--

CREATE TABLE `notification_types` (
  `idkey` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `editable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `has_days` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `default_days` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `has_sessions` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `default_sessions` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `available_methods` set('sms','push','email','chat','info') NOT NULL,
  `default_methods` set('sms','push','email','chat','info') NOT NULL,
  `class` set('announcements','info','marketing','system') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

--
-- Table structure for table `units`
--

CREATE TABLE `units` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `waiting` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `suspended` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `deleted_time` int(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `acl` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `custom_fields` varchar(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `code` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `settings` text NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

--
-- Table structure for table `unit_templates`
--

CREATE TABLE `unit_templates` (
  `unit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idkey` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `method` set('sms','push','email','chat','info') NOT NULL,
  `template` text DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

I didn't include the indexes

You can see https://dbfiddle.uk/8IjWUeOK for the one that works and https://dbfiddle.uk/sZsQou4a for the one that doesn't

Comment: FYI, the column available_methods is type SET

Comment: please add the create table for all involved tables, but if mariadb tells you that the column doesn't exist it usually is so.  also the insert statement as well

Comment: I've updated the question to include the create statements for the involved tables. An insert query is: INSERT INTO `notification_types` (`idkey`, `title`, `editable`, `has_days`, `default_days`, `has_sessions`, `default_sessions`, `available_methods`, `default_methods`, `class`) VALUES ('test_key', 'Test', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'sms', 'sms', 'system');

Comment: The column exists, and the difference between the working trigger and the one that doesn't work is that in tha one that does I daclere a variable and assign the value of NEW.available_methods and use that variable. If I use NEW.available_methods directly in the query it gives the error

Comment: see https://dbfiddle.uk/tQSfQq64  the table unit_templates doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry, I've inserted the worng table create statement. I've corrected the question and I've put the create statement for unit_templates

Comment: You can see https://dbfiddle.uk/8IjWUeOK for the one that works and https://dbfiddle.uk/sZsQou4a for the one that doesn't

Comment: I've tested on mysql 8 instead of mariadb and it works. I think it's a bug in mariadb...

Comment: That isn-t an error, you can not access tables like NEW and it's columns in the select without joining it first. NEW.availqble_methods is not a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the provided information this is written up as a bug [MDEV-32022](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32022)

Comment: I thought so. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is outside the scope of the Object NEW, because you strictly can only access columns that are in the `FROM` clause and what is implemented also variables.

So, you need, at least in MariaDB, like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `add_notification_type` AFTER INSERT ON `notification_types`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    INSERT IGNORE INTO unit_templates (unit, idkey, method)
    SELECT u.id AS unit, NEW.idkey, m.method
    FROM units AS u
    JOIN (
        SELECT 'sms' as method
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'push'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'email'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'chat'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'info'
    ) AS m CROSS JOIN ( SELECT NEW.available_methods) n ON FIND_IN_SET(m.method, NEW.available_methods) > 0;
END
```

which has the same effect.

You can see that it works [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/FR9dx-AY).

Comment: Declaring a variable before the qwery also works and it's probably a little faster (I guess).  Still, it's a little strange behavior or at least unintuitive.

Comment: i doubt that it will be slower and actually it follow the rules of queries to the letter, but i wanted to shoew and explain it

Comment: thanks! Always good to know multiple methods of doing something